# How to find and install Ubuntu 18.04 packages that are equivalent to MacOS packages

Tags: macos, ubuntu, package-managers

Our developers work on MacOS and the system is launched on Ubuntu 18.04.

Developers note that the application server must install the following packages.

> brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg tesseract

Because they work on MacOS, this command installs necessary packages for MacOS.

**My question**

How do I map equivalent packages from MacOS to Ubuntu 18.04 in order to install all the necessary packages for Ubuntu 18.04?

Is there a list of 1 - 1 mappings between MacOS packages and Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: No there isn't. Just use `apt-cache search pango` or similar.

Comment: I tried `apt-cache search cairo` and got a very long list of results. How do I know which one to choose?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a one-to-one list of mapping from Ubuntu to Homebrew packages because the packages tend to contain different things. For example, Debian and Ubuntu tend to package runtime dependencies separately from development dependencies and binaries, and Homebrew tends to ship the entire package as one.

In general, if the thing you want is a shared library, like cairo, you want to look for a package that starts with `lib` and ends with a number or two number separated with a dash. If the thing you want is a development package, it will start with `lib` and end with `-dev`, possibly with some numbers preceding the suffix. For example, the current version of cairo is `libcairo2` and its development package is `libcairo2-dev`.

This is the case because it's possible to have multiple versions of the same shared library installed at the same time. Some programs which have not been updated may use the older version, and some may use the newer version.

If you're looking for binaries, then you probably just want to look for the same name as in Homebrew. For example, `pkg-config` is the name in both Homebrew and Ubuntu. If the binaries come from a shared library, sometimes they'll be in a `-bin` package named like the `-dev` package, say, `libc6-bin`.

If you're looking for packages that are for a particular scripting language, then they'll usually be in a fixed form depending on the language, like `lib*-perl` or `ruby-*`.